# How to prevent overlapping of the light effect with the outline? I have used shape builder tool to get the light effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shadows, graphic-styles

I used shape builder tool to cut a part of ice cream to use it to give a light effect. When I placed it over the ice cream the white part overlaps with the black. But I want the black border visible clearly. I was watching a YouTube tutorial to making this art. In that he just cut the white part with the shape builder tool and placed it on the ice cream. The white part was just before the black border. But in my case it is overlapping. This is the problem I'm facing

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't do that. Edit your original question. The original is still, to me **very unclear**.  In your images I don't see any "white overlapping the black part". I honestly have read the original many times and still can not decipher what the problem is.

Comment: https://youtu.be/yoNr6CjHrjo
Please watch this tutorial from 12:18

Comment: See how the cut part fits perfectly and not mine

Comment: If you are having difficulty with a tutorial, you should perhaps reach out to the creator of the tutorial. Use the comments section on youtube to ask the question. Perhaps you have missed out a step.  It's really hard to unpick someone else's tutorial or to guess which step you may have missed.

Comment: Ok I got it. It is align strike to outside 